# How can I reinitialize a single column in a table using the new ABAP statement FOR

Tags: abap

I have appended two fieldcategory tables together:

```
rt_joined = value #( ( lines of it_left ) ( lines of it_right ) ).
```

Now I would like to reinitialise the col_pos field of the new table.

Previously I would do something like this:

```
loop at rt_joined assigning <ls_fcat>.
  <ls_fcat>-col_pos = sy-tabix.
endloop.
```

Is it possible to do this using the FOR statement (ABAP 7.4 SP8)?

**Edit:  A Simple example to test with:**

```
report test1.

types:
  begin of line,
    col1 type i,
    col2 type i,
    col3 type i,
  end of line,

  itab type standard table of line with empty key.


data: itab2 type standard table of line with empty key.

"Fills the table with some initial data
data(itab) = value itab(
     for j = 11 then j + 10 until j > 40
     ( col1 = j col2 = j + 1 col3 = j + 2  ) ).

"Results IN:
" COL1  COL2    COL3
" 11      12      13
" 21      22      23
" 31      32      33

"Now I copy the table to a second table and try to set col1 as an index
itab2 = itab1.
itab2 = value itab( for i = 1 while i <= lines( itab )
                   ( col1 = i ) ).

"Results IN:
" COL1  COL2    COL3
" 1       0       0
" 2       0       0
" 3       0       0

"I would like this to be:
" COL1  COL2    COL3
" 1       12      13
" 2       22      23
" 3       32      33
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does what I want using the test example:

```
itab2 = value #( for wa in itab index into idx
                 ( col1 = idx
                   col2 = wa-col2
                   col3 = wa-col3 ) ).
itab = itab2.
```

But I don't think this is better than:

```
loop at itab assigning <wa>.
  <wa>-col1 = sy-tabix.
endloop.
```

It is neccesary to move each field in the structure manually, plus there is an additional table assignment, so I'm not sure how it compares performance wise

Comment: Just saw this answer after having done the exercise myself. Yes, I agree, in this exanple the "classical" way still is the best.

Answer (score 1):

This shouldn't be completely off, however I'm not sure if using a new itab for this is necessary:

```
DATA(lt_initialized) = VALUE rt_joined(
                       FOR i = 1 THEN i + 1 WHILE i <= lines( rt_joined )
                       ( col_pos = i  ) ).
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Andreas.  The problem with this solution is that it clears out the other columns in the table.  It also looks like you do need the new itab, which means that in the end the solution really isn't superior to the original.  I'll update my question with a simplified example if you feel inclined to test it.